# 'Set<NSObject>' does not have a member named 'containsObject' after updating XCode & Swift

Tags: xcode, facebook, swift

I've been writing a Swift application over the last week using the latest Facebook iOS SDK v4.0.1. After updating to the latest XCode 6.3 and Swift 1.2 today, I've got a lot of errors. I've been able to fix most of them, mainly new syntax errors like casting, but this error shows up and I haven't been able to find the cause.

```
if result.grantedPermissions.containsObject("email") {
... 
}

'Set<NSObject>' does not have a member named 'containsObject'
```

If anyone has any advice that would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that `result.grantedPermissions` is a native Swift `Set`
which was introduced with Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3) and bridges with `NSSet`.

To check for membership in a `Set`, you can use its `contains()` 
method, for example:

```
if result.grantedPermissions.contains("email") {
    ... 
}
```

For more information, see "Sets" in [Collection Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html) in the Swift documentation.

Comment: Judging from its declaration, the `contains` function is for `SequenceType`. So I guess it costs `O(n)` in time, unless dynamically specialized to `Set<_>`. `Set<_>` itself has `contains` method, so it's better for a good performance, isn't it?

Comment: @findall: Good point. I actually don't know if there is a performance difference, but  `set.contains()` might use the hash value for a quick look-up. I'll update the answer and thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @MartinR that sorted it out, thanks for the response :)